# Configuring the DbContext in MVC6 for Scaffolding

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I am using the new code generator to scaffold standard CRUD controller and views with the new ASP.NET 5 and MVC6. When running the dnx . gen controller command I get the following error message:

> Attempting to figure out the EntityFramework metadata for the model and DbContext
>   There was an error creating the DbContext instance to get the model: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: No data stores are configured. Configure a 
>   data store by overriding OnConfiguring in your DbContext class or in the AddDbContext method when setting up services.

The startup.cs file already has the code that adds the DBContext in the ConfigureServices option, so I am at a loss for how to get this to work.

Comment: I have the same problem with beta5

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps one of these 3 links could help you solve the problem:

[Configure more than one dbcontext in EF 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29054794/configure-more-than-one-dbcontext-in-ef-7)

[Adding DbContextOptions in Startup.cs not registering data store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29945317/adding-dbcontextoptions-in-startup-cs-not-registering-data-store)

[How to cope with "No data stores are configured"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30954372/how-to-cope-with-no-data-stores-are-configured)